# Solving all possible triangles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, triangles

So we're doing oblique triangles -- Law of Sines and all that good stuff =).

I have a bunch of problems that ask you to solve for "all possible triangles that satisfy the given conditions".

For example, one gives $b=45, c=42, \angle C = 38^ \circ$.

This is using the convention that $a$ is opposite of $\angle A$, $b$ is opposite of $\angle B$, and $c$ is opposite of $\angle C$.

How do I go about solving "all possible triangles"?

Thanks!

evamvid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope the following sketch helps:- [image: sketch].

Answer (score 1):

Using Law of Sines we have:

$$\frac b{\sin B} = \frac c{\sin C} \iff \sin B = \frac{b \cdot \sin C}{c}$$

Now solving this you'll get $\angle B \approx 41,27^{\circ}$ or $\angle B \approx 138.72^{\circ}$

Now check both cases. Use $A+B+C = 180^{\circ}$ and Law of Sines to get 2 solutions.

Comment: How does $\sin B = \frac{b \cdot \sin C}{c}$ have two solutions?

Comment: @evamvid Note that you'll get a value in the interval $[0,1]$ and since sine is positive in first and second quadrant we have two solutions. Compute $B = \arcsin \frac{b\cdot sin C}{c}$. Then one solution is $B$ and the other is $180 - B$

Comment: Okay. Also, you said on the second line of text that $\angle B \approx 41,27^{\circ}$. What does this mean? (Or, was it just a typo?)

Comment: As I said $B = \arcsin \frac{b \cdot \sin C}{c}$. Substituting and calculating will provide us with the approximate value of $B$

Comment: What's the 41 in this case? The way I read your answer was that solving $\frac{b \cdot \sin C}{c}$ gave $41,27^{\circ}$ and $138.72^{\circ}$. Where does the 41 come from?

Comment: Use arcsin function on your calculator

Comment: I actually left my calculator at school today. =). But what I don't understand is the function of the comma.

Comment: What comma? arcsin is inverse of sine. It's sometimes denoted as $sin^{-1}$

Comment: The comma in $\angle B \approx 41,27^{\circ}$

Comment: It means $41,27$ degrees. The angle isn't an integer value.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something simple; I still don't understand. Break it down for me =)