# Similar Triangles

Tags: geometry

I was reading a book and came across the following question...

$\text{If in triangles ABC and DEF, we have } \angle A =\angle D \ \text{and AB:DE=BC:EF, then prove that } \angle C= \angle F\ \text{or} \ \angle C+\angle F=180^\circ $

I don't have any specific ideas to prove this ... I have so far only shown that if both are acute angled triangles then first condition holds ......By taking three cases

$(i)\angle E = \angle B$,  $(ii)\angle E > \angle B$,  $(iii)\angle E < \angle B$
It's easy to prove the first

but I don't know how to prove this more generally for all possible configurations

....

Any hints would be appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember.  If you have a point $E$,  a line $DF$, and a length $k$ then either i) there are two points on $DF$ that are $k$ distance for $E$.  ii) The is exactly one point on $DF$ that is $k$ distance from $E$ and the segment formed is perpendicular to $DF$.  or iii) There are no points of $DF$ that are $k$ distance from $E$.

So lets try to construct triangle $DEF$ from what we know.  Plot point $D$.  Construct a line $L$ through $D$.  Construct $\angle D = \angle A$.  Plot a point $E$.  Find the ratio of $AB$ to $DE$.  Calculate the distance $k$ so that $k$ is the proportional to $BC$ as $AB$ is to $DE$.

Now try to figure which points on $L$ that are $k$ distance from $E$ can be candidates for point $F$.  There must be at least one as we can make a triangle similar to $ABC$.  (So iii) is out of the question.).  If there is one such point then call it $F$ and $\angle F = \angle C$ is a right angle as is $ABC$ and $DEF$ and $ABC$ are similar *AND* $\angle F + \angle C = 180$.

The third option is there are two points $F$ and $F'$.  Wolog $D, F', F$ are the colinear order.

Call $\angle DFE = \angle F$ and $\angle DF'E = \angle F'$.

As $EF = EF'$ then $EFF'$ is isoceles.  So $\angle EF'F = 180 - \angle F' = \angle F$.

Note one of the triangles $DEF$ or $DEF'$ is similar to $ABC$ so either $\angle C$ is equal to either $\angle F$ or to $\angle F' = 180 - \angle F$

(see image)

[image]

In the image:  $\angle F = \angle EF'F = 180 - \angle DF'E $.

These are the only two possible triangles where $\angle D = \angle A$, $DE = k*AB$ and $DF$ (or $DF'$) $= k*BC$.  Now one of these two triangles must be the triangle that is similar to $\triangle ABC$.

So either $\angle C = \angle F$ or $\angle C = DF'E = 180 - \angle F$.

Answer (score 3):

AB : DE = BC : EF implies AB : BC = DE : EF. This further means $\dfrac { \sin C }{\sin A} = \dfrac {\sin F}{\sin D}$ by sine law.

A = D implies $\sin C = \sin F$

Then, either $C = F$ or C = $180^0 – F$

Comment: Good answer...but is there any proof without trigonometry

Comment: @user35508  I have a work done on this topic. Give me some time to search for it.

Comment: @user35508 See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690645/solving-all-possible-triangles/692290#692290 The question/answer is different but the reason behind is equally applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt:

$ \triangle ABC$:

Extend $AB$ to $E$,  and extend $AC$ to $F$.

Consider  $ \triangle ABC$, and $\triangle AEF$.

Given: $AE:AB= EF:BC $.

Then   $EF = BC(AE/AB)$.

Draw a line parallel to $BC$ through $E$, let it intersect line $AF$ in $F'$.

Intercept Theorem (Similar triangles):

$EF' : BC = AE: AB$;

Hence $EF' = BC(AE/AB)$.

We conclude : length $EF$ equals length $EF'$.

1) Length $EF$ > distance from $E$ to line $AB$ extended.

A circle with center $E$ and radius $r: =$ length $EF$ intersects line $AB$ extended in two distinct  points $F$  and $F'$ .

A) $ \triangle ABC$ is similar to $\triangle  AEF'$.
$(EF' || BC)$. Corresponding angles are equal.

B)$\triangle EFF'$ is isosceles , $r$ = length $EF'$ = length $EF$, the two base angles at $FF'$ are equal.

$\angle EFA = 180° - \angle EF'A$.

2)  Distance from  $E$ to $AB$ extended equals  $r$.

Circle touches, i.e. $F = F'$, only one solution :

$\angle EFA = \angle EF'A = 90°$.

3)  $ r$ < distance, no solution.

Comments welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Superimpose $∆ABC$ on $∆DEF$. As $\angle A = \angle D$, (AB,DE) and (AC,DF) overlap. Since the question involves 'lengths' and condition is imposed on C and F, we have to find the possible positions in which C and F can be placed to satisfy the condition. Let us assume that the condition ($AB:DE = BC:EF$) is true for certain points C and F. Taking E as the centre and EF as the radius draw an arc. Name the points as $F_1$ and $F_2$ . Similarly for C we will have $C_1$ and $C_2$. $∆EF_1F_2$ and $∆BC_1C_2$ are isosceles triangle. Corresponding to each value of C there exists two values of F. Since there exists two 'nominees' in each case and we know that one of them is a similar triangle so either $\angle BC_2A = \angle EF_2D$ or $\angle BC_1A = \angle EF_1D$.

Case 1.

$$\angle BC_2A = \angle EF_2D$$
$$\angle EF_2F_1 = 180° - \angle EF_2D = 180° - \angle BC_2A$$
Therefore either $$\angle F = \angle C$$ or $$\angle F + \angle C = 180°$$

Case 2.

$$\angle BC_1A = \angle EF_1D$$
$$\angle EF_2F_1 = \angle BC_1A$$
$$\angle EF_2D = 180° - \angle EF_2F_1 = 180° - \angle BC_1A$$
Therefore either $$\angle F = \angle C$$ or $$\angle F + \angle C = 180°$$

When $\angle BCA = 90°$ , $\angle F = 90°$.